# Why can't I rotate text on iPad?

Tags: html, ios, css, ipad

I am building a website on which I have a left sidebar. In this sidebar, I show text which I need to rotate 90 degrees left. On my desktop browser (Chrome) it looks fine, with "1. klasse", "2. klasse" etc being rotated:

[image]

On an iPad however, I can't get the text to rotate(tried in Safari and Chrome):

[image]

This is the styling I use for each text element:

```
-webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
-o-transform: rotate(90deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
transform: rotate(180deg);
```

Here is the website for your reference: http://lektieninja.dk

Update:
As to the comment asking for media query: there is a media query around the sidebar, to not show sidebar on mobile phone. However this should not have any influence on iPad:

```
@media (max-width:@bs4xsmall-max-width) {
    display: none;
}
```

bs4xssmall-max-width defined as:

```
@bs4xsmall-max-width: 543px;
```

Comment: Is the css in a media query? Or is the text always supposed to be rotated? If its in a media query, post that in your original question.

Comment: @Pat: Please see updated question.